# Set all panels to be closed by default or remember settings by file?

Tags: interface

I'm currently working on a very small screen, and I'd like to have all the panels closed by default and only open the ones I need manually, or if possible even just remember my last open panels when I save a project. Is it possible?

[image: Open and Closed panels]

*(open (1) and closed (2) panels in the editor)*

I know I can use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>LMB</kbd> to open a panel singularly, and that alone is a great help, but this would be even better.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. Open blender.
2. Set the screens the way you want them.

Save your new layout as default by saving the startup file.

In the top menu use File > **Save Startup file.

[image]

(For older versions 2.7x) Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> <kbd>U</kbd> to save the current file as the [startup file](https://www.blender.org/manual/preferences/startup_file.html?highlight=startup#startup-file).

[image]

From then on, every time you open blender you'll be presented with the layout you've customized.

Setings are always saved so that when you reopen a file it will open with the windows in the same way they where when the file was saved.

If you want to override this behavior unclick the **Load UI** in when opening a file:

[image]

[image]

To go reload blender's original settings you can always go to the top menu and use File->**Load Factory Settings**