# Customize Workspace and disabling editors

Tags: interface, customization

I've read a lot about this but I can't find a direct answer for 2.8. I would like to modify Blender's UI as to minimize clutter, since there are a lot of features I don't use.

I've read that one can modify/design a workspace and save this in Blenders startup file. I can make a new workspace, but I see where changes are supposed to be made.

[Here they only make new workspaces](https://chiaroscorner.wordpress.com/2019/08/13/how-to-arrange-and-save-workspaces-in-blender-2-8). Is that all you can do?

Can I make a workspace where I remove all other regions and editor than the 3D viewport like this image?

[image]

Comment: As always: What *exactly* you want to do?

Comment: So Blender can have many workspaces.  Designed by you as well.  CRUD Create Read Update Delete.  The typical operations.  I find some of you statements unclear. You may want to make your question clearer.  There are many online tutorials on Blender Workspaces on the video site with the name that rhymes with noonoob.  This portion of what you wrote is unclear to me [but I see where changes are supposed to be made.]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Set all panels to be closed by default or remember settings by file?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/43877/set-all-panels-to-be-closed-by-default-or-remember-settings-by-file)

Comment: Or this link: [can screen layouts be locked](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/34174/can-screen-layouts-or-workspaces-be-locked)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can screen layouts or workspaces be locked?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/34174/can-screen-layouts-or-workspaces-be-locked)